# Qt ClickToFlash

Tags: qt

I have installed ClickToFlash plugin on my mac machine.
When I have pages with flash in QWebview I have a crash in QtWebKit.
Does anybody has the same problem? How I can solve it?

Thanks,
Gennadii

Answer (score 0):

If, and only if you provide more detailed information (like a crash log), some more description and some example code to reproduce your problem, you might be able to expect a serious answer to your problem.